# I want key `A` to be held for at least three seconds without a break. Make sure that is the case

Tags: c, winapi, timer, keyevent

I want key `A` to be held for at least three seconds without a break. If the key press is interrupted, the three-second period should apply again.
This is my previous program. Unfortunately, while the `timer()` procedure is running, the program does not notice anything about the release of the button or pressing it again.

My question to you is: what can I do?

I want to stay in C.

My IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.11.2.

I work with Windows 10.

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) // Visual Studio doesn't want to see old functions like ‘scanf’.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <time.h>

bool supposed_to_run = true;
VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD);
long long waited = 0ll;
time_t Time_of_the_keydown_event;
bool triggered = false;


void timer()
{
    Time_of_the_keydown_event;
    time_t _to = time(&_to) + 3ll;

    do
    {
        Time_of_the_keydown_event = time(&Time_of_the_keydown_event);
    } while (Time_of_the_keydown_event < _to && triggered);

}

void Logic(INPUT_RECORD rec)
{
    if (rec.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!rec.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
    {
        triggered = false;
        return;
    }

    switch (rec.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
    {
    case VK_SHIFT:
        break;
    case VK_CONTROL:
        break;
    case VK_SPACE:
        break;
    case VK_LEFT:
        break;
    case VK_UP:
        break;
    case VK_RIGHT:
        break;
    case VK_DOWN:
        break;
    case 0x41: /*A*/
        triggered = true;
        timer();
        
        printf("A\n");
        break;
    case 0x51: /*Q*/
        break;
    case 0x5A:  /*Z*/
        supposed_to_run = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    INPUT_RECORD rec{};
    HANDLE hConInp = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD ReadCount = 0;

    //Change_size_position_and_color();

    while (supposed_to_run)
    {
        ReadConsoleInput(hConInp, &rec, 1, &ReadCount);
        Logic(rec); 
    }
    

    // end program
    printf("\nProgramm wird beendet. Dr\x81 \bcken Sie eine Taste und \x27 \bEnter\x27 \b.\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that in C, you must also add `#include <stdbool.h>` if you want to use the `bool` data type, which you don't have to do in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the function [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject). That function allows you to wait for new console input to become available, and also allows you to specify a timeout, which should be 3 seconds in your case.

Depending on the return value of that function, you will know whether new console input has occurred or whether the timeout has expired.

```
switch ( WaitForSingleObject( hConInp, 3000 ) )
{
case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    //handle new console input
    //ReadConsoleInput will not block if called now
    break;
case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    //handle timeout
    break;
default:
    //handle error
}
```

However, this solution has one problem. While holding down the key, the key will automatically repeat, generating new input events. Therefore, the timeout of 3 seconds will probably never expire (unless you have configured your operating system to have a very long repeat delay).

Therefore, you will have to ignore these key down events and call `WaitForSingleObject` again, but this time not with a timeout of 3 seconds again. Instead, the new timeout should be the remaining time of the original 3 seconds.

In your code, you are using the ISO C function [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time). However, this function has a precision of only one second, which may not be accurate enough. Therefore, you may want to use the platform-specific function [`GetTickCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount) instead.

I believe I was able to get your program to work, by making the changes mentioned above. Here is my code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool supposed_to_run = true;
bool triggered = false;
bool require_release = false;
DWORD remaining_timeout;

void Logic( INPUT_RECORD *p_rec )
{
    //only handle keyboard events
    if ( p_rec->EventType != KEY_EVENT )
        return;

    if (!p_rec->Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
    {
        if ( triggered )
        {
            printf( "removing trigger\n" );
            triggered = false;
        }
        else if ( require_release && p_rec->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode == 0x41 )
        {
            printf( "key has been released and timeout may now be triggered again\n" );
            require_release = false;
        }
        return;
    }

    switch (p_rec->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
    {
    case VK_SHIFT:
        break;
    case VK_CONTROL:
        break;
    case VK_SPACE:
        break;
    case VK_LEFT:
        break;
    case VK_UP:
        break;
    case VK_RIGHT:
        break;
    case VK_DOWN:
        break;
    case 0x41: /*A*/
        if ( !triggered && !require_release )
        {
            printf( "triggering timeout\n" );
            triggered = true;
            remaining_timeout = 3000;
        }
        break;
    case 0x51: /*Q*/
        break;
    case 0x5A:  /*Z*/
        supposed_to_run = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    INPUT_RECORD rec;
    HANDLE hConInp = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD ReadCount;

    while (supposed_to_run)
    {
        if ( triggered )
        {
            bool timeout_expired = false;

            DWORD start_time = GetTickCount();

            switch ( WaitForSingleObject( hConInp, remaining_timeout ) )
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                break;
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                timeout_expired = true;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf( stderr, "unexpected error!" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            DWORD time_expired = GetTickCount() - start_time;

            if ( !timeout_expired )
            {
                //It is possible that WaitForSingleObject did not report
                //a timeout, but that GetTickCount now reports that the
                //timeout expired. We should consider this also a timeout.
                if ( time_expired >= remaining_timeout )
                    timeout_expired = true;
            }

            if ( timeout_expired )
            {
                triggered = false;
                require_release = true;
                printf( "A\n" );
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                remaining_timeout -= time_expired;
            }
        }

        ReadConsoleInput( hConInp, &rec, 1, &ReadCount );
        Logic( &rec ); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After the user holds down the key <kbd>A</kbd> for three seconds, it will display that character on the screen. Afterwards, a new timeout will not be triggered until the user releases the key and then presses it again.

Comment: Hi Andreas,

I just saw that you edited your post. I have to say thank you!

_I am not sure if that is what you want._ No, as soon as the "event" has been triggered, it should _not_ be feasible to trigger it again before acknowledging. But first of all, I have to develop myself further. We'll sort that out then. ;)

Comment: @Daniel: I have changed the code so that it now requires the user to release the key, before a new timeout can be triggered. I have tested it a bit and it seems to work.